# mojave python 3.7 libmysqlclient.21.dylib issue

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

mojave python 3.7 libmysqlclient.21.dylib issue

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Hey there! It looks like you may have cut off the first bit of your error. Regardless, it would be helpful if you created a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that gives the same error, and include that in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is working in terminal when I run command python3 manage.py runserver, but in the pycharm community, It has error for mysqlclient

Comment: It looks like a missing library for MySQL, but I'm not sure why it would be working via commandline vs in PyCharm. From Terminal, could you run: `mdfind -name libmysqlclient` and `mdfind -name _mysql.cpython` and add the output to the question?

Answer (score 0):

My project with Python 3.6 was lookin for libmysqlclient.21.dylib.

I installed `brew install mysql-client`. It installed mysql-client 8.0. it has libmysqlclient.21.dylib. Where as i wanted to use mysql@5.6.

So I copied the libmysqlclient.21.dylib from /usr/local/Cellar/mysql-client/8.0.19/lib to  /usr/local/lib/

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/mysql-client/8.0.19/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib`

So its a Python , mysql , mysqlclient version mismatch issue .

mysql@5.6 has libmysqlclient.18
mysql@5.7 has libmysqlclient.20

Follow the above work around in MAC OSX Catalina.